# Visual Studio 2017 command line build not finding header files

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I just installed the latest version of visual studio 2017 (15.3.4), the "Desktop development with C++" package. I didn't install any other tools/packages as I'm not 100% sure what they're for (I'm just trying to write a simple C++ program).

I was able to compile a simple "hello world" program using the IDE, but when I tried to compile the code using the "Development Command Prompt for VS 2017" I keep getting an error saying `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: whatever.h: No such file or directory` (NOTE: `whatever.h` is just a place holder for the header file name).

For example, here's my c++ code, [following a VS2017 walk through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line),

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
   cout << "Hello, world, from Visual C++!" << endl;
}
```

When I execute the build from the command line

```
C:\Users\username\source\hello>cl /EHsc hello.cpp
```

I get the following output

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25508.2 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.1
1.25503\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cor
ecrt.h': No such file or directory
```

I found the header file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt`, which doesn't appear in my `PATH` when I type "PATH" in the command prompt. I tried to add the known path using

```
PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt;%PATH%
```

and still no luck. I tried to open the command prompt as an administrator, no luck. I tried to include the path

```
C:\Users\username\source\hello>cl /EHsc /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\1
0\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt" hello.cpp
```

outputs the following

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25508.2 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25508.2
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello.exe
hello.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'uuid.lib'
```

and now I have a linking problem, but at least it seems it found the correct header files. Again, I did nothing but the default installation.

This error occurs with all command line build attempts. Specifically, I'm trying to build the latest `boost` library (1.65) because I need `filesystem` in the program I'm working with. Following their "Getting started guide", I couldn't even get past the first step, executing "bootstrap", as it spit out a bunch of `C1083` errors complaining about missing header files.

Anyway, the failed command line build of `hello.cpp` (as stated above) suggests something went wrong with my default install of VS2017. I'm using 64-bit Windows 7 Professional SP1. I didn't get any errors during the installation process and I even uninstalled and reinstalled the program to arrive at the same issue.

Is there something I'm missing on how to use the command line build approach?

Answer (score 0):

This won't fix whatever went wrong during VC installation or your errors with bjam (the correct way to build boost), but for that last LNK1104 error:

> C:\Users\username\source\hello>cl /EHsc /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt" hello.cpp **/link uuid.lib**

For others who would forgo the IDE, I recommend only [installing the build tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/?__hstc=268264337.4ade71b63cf02f370619551538e0cf64.1506210299191.1506210299191.1506210299191.1&__hssc=268264337.2.1506210299192&__hsfp=468882657).

Comment: I'm not trying to forgo the IDE. I want to build the boost library so I can access the 'filesystem' library tools. Their "Getting started guide" follows the command line approach. Due to all the errors I was getting, I went back to the basics i.e. "hello world". I did nothing but the default installation of VS2017 as highlighted above. Since the command line is failing to build "hello world", clearly there's something wrong.